# Is it okay to say from " the physics point of view " ?

Tags: expressions, science

So I am a mathematician, and I am trying to explain the consequence of an equation from " the physiscs points of view". 
Is it okay to state it in this manner:  "from  the physics point of view "   ?

Comment: From the physicist's point of view.

Comment: @Sprottenwels Ok, but I don't see much wrong with "from the physics point of view" either. The word "physics" is simply being used as a noun modifier. It is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not a native speaker. I thought it sounded odd.

Comment: I don't think either is going to sound convincing. Equations don't have consequences: the laws they model (or attempt to), or more precisely, the obeying of such laws, do / does. A transferred usage (cf 'I'll boil a kettle') is, in my opinion, too imprecise in a scientific article.  A little more context is required. Note that Nigel J's answer avoids the mention of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'[From a physics point of view](https://www.quora.com/From-a-physics-point-of-view-what-is-happening-when-a-device-overheats), what is happening when a device overheats ?' is the title of a paper written by Rob van den Berg, Master Student in Theoretical Physics. So it would seem to be an acceptable phrase if a physicist uses it.